# Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=64 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 64.)"

Tags: nsxmlparser, nsxmlparsererrordomain

What deos the error 64 in NSXMLParserDomain Code=64 mean? I am using an NSXMLParser to parse my XML data. But i am getting the above mentioned error. Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it out. The error comes when the XMl contains errors at the start up. U can validate the XMl using w3schools here  [http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp[How](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp%5BHow) to validate an XML][1](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Its also happens if the XML contains some extra line before the xml tag starts.