# Webservice data is not loading in NSXMLParse in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to i phone programming.I am getting some response from webservice.But its not loading that data in nsxmlparser.

## import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,NSXMLParserDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{

    NSMutableData *webData;
    NSMutableString *soapResults;
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
    BOOL xmlResults;
    NSMutableArray *arr_code,*arr_name;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *arr_code,*arr_name;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableData *webData;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableString *soapResults;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSXMLParser *xmlParser;
```

## import "ViewController.h"

```
@synthesize arr_code,arr_name,webData,soapResults,xmlParser,nb,table;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    arr_code=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arr_name=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    xmlResults =FALSE;
     NSString *soapMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                           "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                           "<soap:Body>\n"

                           "<OnlineStatus xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                           "<CafeName>Cyber Cafe Name</CafeName>\n"
                           "<FromDate>2012-03-01</FromDate>\n"
                           "<ToDate>2013-05-03</ToDate></OnlineStatus>\n"
                           "</soap:Body>\n"

                           "</soap:Envelope>"];
    NSLog(@"%@",soapMessage);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ebidmanagerdemo.com/gjHouseOnline/xml/XMLDataService.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/OnlineStatus" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
      if(theConnection) {
        webData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    NSLog(@"%@",msgLength);
            [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR with theConnenction");
    }

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"];
    theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"];
    theXML = [theXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
       NSLog(@" getting in xml %@",theXML);
    NSLog(@"XMl is workinggggggggg");
  xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:webData];
    NSXMLParser *aslamxml =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:dataa];  
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser parse];
    NSLog(@" iiiiii %@",xmlParser);
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
   attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"fsdfsd");
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MachineIP"])
    {
      if(!soapResults)
        {
            soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        }
        xmlResults = YES;

    }
    else
    {
        if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MachineIP"])
        {


            if(!soapResults)
            {
                soapResults = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

            }
            xmlResults = YES;

        }
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if( xmlResults )
    {
        [self.soapResults appendString: string];
        NSLog(@"soap result %@",soapResults);

    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MachineIP"])
    {
        xmlResults = FALSE;
        [arr_code addObject:soapResults];
       // NSLog(@"hello %@",arr_code);

        soapResults = nil;
    }
    else {
        if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"MachineIP"])
        {
            xmlResults = FALSE;
            [arr_name addObject:soapResults];
            NSLog(@"hiii %@",arr_name);

            soapResults = nil;
        }
    }
    [table reloadData];

}
```

I am getting output like this
If i give      NSLog(@" getting in xml %@",theXML);
In console its displaying below think

```
2013-05-27 19:13:35.735 NewC Newcafezee[1202:11303] DONE. Received Bytes: 18345
2013-05-27 19:13:35.737 NewC Newcafezee[1202:11303]  getting in xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><OnlineStatusResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><OnlineStatusResult><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet>
  <xs:schema id="Result" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="Result" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="Table">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SystemDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CafeDateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="LicenseNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MachineIP" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="TotalClients" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="IdleClients" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="BusyClients" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="DummyIdle" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="DummyBusy" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PCUsageSessions" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PCUsageMinutes" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="SessionMessage" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CreatedBy" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CreatedDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Cybercafe" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="AdminPassword" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MajorVersion" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="MinorVersion" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="SalesAmount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PurchasesAmount" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Revision" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="CZLicense" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <Result>
      <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <SystemDateTime>2012-09-20T00:00:00-06:00</SystemDateTime>
        <CafeDateTime>2012-09-18T11:01:54-06:00</CafeDateTime>
        <LicenseNumber>cc</LicenseNumber>
        <MachineIP>192.168.13.167</MachineIP>
        <TotalClients>0</TotalClients>
        <IdleClients>0</IdleClients>
        <BusyClients>0</BusyClients>
        <DummyIdle>0</DummyIdle>
        <DummyBusy>0</DummyBusy>
        <PCUsageSessions>0</PCUsageSessions>
        <PCUsageMinutes>0</PCUsageMinutes>
        <SessionMessage>LVCLPRLbSCTC</SessionMessage>
        <CreatedBy>1</CreatedBy>
        <CreatedDate>2012-09-20T00:00:00-06:00</CreatedDate>
        <Cybercafe>Cyber Cafe Name</Cybercafe>
        <Email>YOURMAIL@CAFE.COM</Email>
        <AdminPassword>admin1</AdminPassword>
        <MajorVersion>1</MajorVersion>
        <MinorVersion>0</MinorVersion>
        <SalesAmount>0.0000</SalesAmount>
        <PurchasesAmount>0.0000</PurchasesAmount>
        <Revision>0</Revision>
        <CZLicense />
      </Table>
    </Result>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet></OnlineStatusResult></OnlineStatusResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

But if give 
 NSLog(@" iiiiii %@",xmlParser); it is for XMLParser its not loading in NSXMlparser its showing empty please Can any body tell me that what is mistake in this code?I am not getting why its not loading in NSXMLparser.

```
2013-05-27 19:13:35.738 NewC Newcafezee[1202:11303] XMl is workinggggggggg
2013-05-27 19:13:35.739 NewC Newcafezee[1202:11303]  iiiiii <NSXMLParser: 0x7191d20>
```

I am getting error code some think like this below

```
2013-05-27 19:43:35.962 NewC Newcafezee[1291:11303] error parsing XML: Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code 64 ) http://www.ebidmanagerdemo.com/gjHouseOnline/xml/XMLDataService.asmx
```

In above output i am getting two time below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

That is main reason for error ra?please tell me what is mistake?

Comment: Implement parser:parseErrorOccurred:

Comment: Your XML response contains two `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` declarations. Only one declaration is allowed per document. Also as @Wain mentioned, you need to implement parser error delegate method to get the errors in parsing response.

Comment: 2013-05-27 19:43:35.962 NewC Newcafezee[1291:11303] error parsing XML: Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code 64 ) http://www.ebidmanagerdemo.com/gjHouseOnline/xml/XMLDataService.asmx

Comment: Edit your old question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769363/not-able-to-parse-webservices-getting-data-in-iphone instead of creating new one.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the value in `soapResults` array. Try printing it in the following method:
`parserDidEndDocument`.

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
```

Answer (score 0):

first know the error

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"error:%@",parseError);

}
```

Comment: Ya i getting error 64

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039161/error-domain-nsxmlparsererrordomain-code-64-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed) and Try to remove the <META> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Change in didEndElement xmlResults = FALSE;       to       xmlResults = NO;