# Xml parsing error in ios to get attribute values

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I have problem with xml parsing

I got an XML response from the server with this header:

```
?xml version="1.0"?
```

So I can't parse it and I can't get my attribute values. In same structure static I will parse else it won't work .

If i add my header file statically like this  `?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?`  it will work fine .
However if I dynamically append this `"encoding=\"UTF-8\"` in my xml it shows an error

```
Parser error Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=64 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 64.)"
```

[see the full xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307330/after-did-finish-loading-i-cant-get-my-xml-attribute-values-in-ios)

Comment: If you have already asked a Question then why are you asking again ? You can always edit your Question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039161/error-domain-nsxmlparsererrordomain-code-64-the-operation-couldnt-be-completed

Comment: @Tendulkar i have done validation in w3 school it show no error.if i will add  like dis <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> it will work fine,dynamically i will append in xml it shows error

Comment: @Vin yet know i did't get any solution i have implemented many ways.

Comment: @Balaji : In that case, you have to go through your Question again and try to find out why no one was able to give the Answer of your Question. You should rephrase your Question or try to explain it in a way so that an unknown user can also understand what you want to say. You should add more details in the same Question on what you tried and where exactly you are failing, instead of asking duplicate Questions.

Comment: @Vin i have problem in only xml in header file i don't have this type of header in xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> i have recieve like dis  <?xml version="1.0"?> so i cant parse it and get the attribute values dis my problem